# Set multiple responseType in Angular

Tags: angular

I am fetching data from back-end which is in the form of JSON. Everything is working perfectly except for one thing. Since, I am using JWT and sending my own generated message from the backend incase, token expires the Angular is throwing a parsing error. I know it's because I haven't set the `responseType` to text in Angular but, what I want to ask is that how can I handle multiple responseType in Angular?

My code:

```
this.http.get<{[key: string]: Admin}>('http://localhost:3000/api/adminData', {params})
  .pipe(map(responseData => {
      
      console.log(responseData);

      if(JSON.stringify(responseData).includes('No Token Provided'))
      {
        this.noTokenError = true;
      }

      else if(JSON.stringify(responseData).includes('Authorization Failed. Token Expired. Please 
              Login Again.'))
      {
        this.authFailedError = true;
      }

      //rest of the code
```

How can I tell Angular to handle the responseType on its own since I don't know what it's going to be, JSON or Text? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this.http.get<{[key: string]: Admin} **| { someKey: yourType }**>

try like this.

Comment: I am using that key to iterate through the elements, Admin is an interface. It's not related to the responseType.

Comment: You can use multiple interfaces like `Admin`

Comment: How? Can you please elaborate a little bit? What you're saying is that the Angular will automatically assign the value to the right interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Type Guard.

```
this.http.get<{[key: string]: Admin} | string>('http://localhost:3000/api/adminData', {params})
  .pipe(
    map(responseData => {
      
      const isString = (responseData: {[key: string]: Admin} | string): responseData is string => {
        return typeof responseData === 'string';
      }
      
      const isObject = (responseData: {[key: string]: Admin} | string): responseData is {[key: string]: Admin} => {
        return typeof responseData !== 'string';
      }
    
    
      if (isString(responseData)) {
        // Code for responseData is string;
      }
      
      if (isObject(responseData)) {
        // Code for responseData is {[key: string]: Admin}
      }
```